# Can I introspect a Regex's interpolated value?

Tags: regex, raku, string-interpolation, rakudo

In the code below, the Regex `$r` clearly "knows" that it contains the text `bar` – that's how it is able to match against the Str `bar`.  But `.gist` and `.raku` report that `$r` contains the variable `$foo` without saying what value `$foo` contains.  Is there any way to get `$r` to tell me its computed value?

```
sub f {
    my $foo = 'bar';
    g(rx/$foo/);
}

sub g($r) {
    say $r.gist;
    say 'bar' ~~ rx/$r/;
}

f # OUTPUT:  rx/$foo/
  #          ｢bar｣
```

(I know that I can access the same information by manually parsing `$r`, finding all variables, and then walking `&g`'s `callframe`s to find the values of the variables.  But that seems like a fairly brittle hack to get at info that the Regex clearly already knows, at least on some level.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can I introspect a Regex's interpolated value?

No, because it hasn't *been* interpolated, just like in a closure `{ say $a }` we'd not consider `$a` as being interpolated either, but rather say that it is closed over. A variable in a regex compiles into a lookup of that variable, the lookup being made each time the regex is evaluated. This can be confirmed by changing the value of the variable between evaluations of the regex:

```
my $var = "foo";
my $rx = rx/$var/;
say "foobar" ~~ $rx;    # ｢foo｣
$var = "bar";
say "foobar" ~~ $rx;    # ｢bar｣
```

The larger principle at work here is that in Raku, regexes are not strings that are handled by some regex implementation in the standard library, but instead parts of the compiled program, and subject to the same closure semantics as any other block or thunk.

That they `gist` to their source is mostly there for pragmatic reasons (better diagnostic output in the `Test` module was probably the driving force), however it is done precisely by the source code string being attached to the `Regex` object at compile time. By runtime, it's all bytecode, and the source string you see isn't involved.

Comment: Thanks.  That fully answers my question about Regexs, but raises new questions about how lexical scoping works in Raku.  I would have expected `{say $var }` to have closed over `$a` at the time it was defined, but it looks like it closes over the final value of `$a` at the end of the scope in which it was defined.  Is that right?

Comment: No, closures *reference* their outer scope, and read (or even write) variables in that. Consider a function generator like `sub counter($start is copy) { -> { $start++ } }; my $c = counter(40); say $c(); say $c(); say $c();`, which relies on closure semantics not being about value, but also reference. (This is in contrast with the Java model, where the closure is created with values, which then may not be mutated.)

Comment: Aha, thanks; that clears up my confusion.  The semantics of binding to a read-only reference are close enough to those of copying a value that I was able to mix them up for quite a while without getting tripped up too badly.  But once you pointed out the difference, it all clicks into place. :)